# My program output is not getting updated in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

I have my c code below, It is working fine for one time, after calling the function again, it is giving the same result. The buffer is not getting updated.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char *EpochToMMDDYYYY(long );

int main() {
    long epoch = 1492151737;
    printf("date of %ld is %s\n",epoch,EpochToMMDDYYYY(epoch));
    long ep = 1492222737;
    printf("date of %ld is %s\n",epoch,EpochToMMDDYYYY(ep));
    long epc = 1491111737;
    printf("date of %ld is %s\n",epoch,EpochToMMDDYYYY(epc));
    return 0;

}

char *EpochToMMDDYYYY(long ep)
{
    struct tm tm;
    char b[25];
    memset(b,0,sizeof(b));
    //setenv("TZ", "PST8PDT", 1);
    /* set your own time zone PST8PDT for PDT timezone */
    //tzset();

    char epoch[20];
    sprintf(epoch,"%ld",ep);

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    strptime(epoch, "%s", &tm);
    strftime(b, sizeof(b), "%m%d%Y", &tm);
    puts(b); /* -> 04 24 2017 */
    return b;
}
```

Ouput as follows

```
04142017
date of 1492151737 is 04142017
04142017
date of 1492151737 is 04142017
04022017
date of 1492151737 is 04022017
```

Can Anyone tell me the reason behind this, and solution for this?

Comment: `b` is invalid outside `EpochToMMDDYYYY` function scope.

Comment: Where can I make replacements to get the output exactly? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `char b[25];` --> `static char b[25];` as simple fix

Comment: Returning pointer to something that no longer exists after the function has returned.   Using that causes the caller to exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: 1 Thank you @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a pointer to memory held locally in your function:

```
char *EpochToMMDDYYYY(long ep) {
    char b[25];
    ...
    return b;
}
```

When the function returns, `b` goes out of scope and is not valid any more. Accessing such memory leads to undefined behaviour, and one such possible undefined behaviour could yield your output.

To overcome this, I see two approaches:

First, you could change local variable `b` to be static, i.e. `char b[25]; --> static char b[25]` as suggested by BLUEPIXY. Note, however, that then a later call overrides the result of a previous call. This could be problematic if the result is not copied or finally used in the meanwhile:

```
printf("%s %s", EpochToMMDDYYYY(epoch), EpochToMMDDYYYY(ep))
```

This will print the same value twice, and it is even unspecified which one.

So, second, I'd actually suggest to pass the memory to which the result is written as function argument. Change the code as follows:

```
void EpochToMMDDYYYY(long, char*);

int main() {
    char result[25];

    long epoch = 1492151737;
    EpochToMMDDYYYY(epoch, result);
    printf("date of %ld is %s\n",epoch,result);

    long ep = 1492222737;
    EpochToMMDDYYYY(ep, result);
    printf("date of %ld is %s\n",epoch,result);

    ...
    return 0;

}

void *EpochToMMDDYYYY(long ep, char* b) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: What should I do now? could you suggest any replacements?

Comment: Probably better of returning `char *` than `void *`, since the intent is to treat the return value like a string (`%s`).   Also, if the intent is `printf("%s %s", EpochToMMDDYYYY(epoch, buffer), EpochToMMDDYYYY(ep, buffer))` then the output will be the same both time.   It would be necessary to pass different buffers.